# ajax page template

Tags: ajax, page-template, front-end

I am creating a wp theme that gets all its data via ajax (using ajax-admin.php).
Now, I've set a div that would have the html of the page there (in the index.php file).
My index.php is a simple one, like this:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="ajaxdata"></div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I also setup ajax (as I said via ajax-admin.php), and it works with simple content (for example echoing there some jquery generated text or retrieving a post/page.

I have created 4 types of pages as page templates. article_1, article_2, article_3, article_4. What I want is the function that returns the page template html into a variable applied with the page data from an id. Is there a ready function on the codex or a filter/action to do that?

Comment: Assuming you're talking about pages only, there's [get_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page).

Comment: no, I have covered that, along with the page metadata. The problem is that I have a page template assigned to the page (one of the four article_x) that I also need rendered, have the result into a php variable and then echo it to the ajax mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, it's an easier way, using get_template_part and some php magic.
What you do is get the page name from post_metadata filter the filename without the extension and add it to get_template_part. Of course all your data must conform a predefined variable (or just pass the id to the template) because you have to use a global $post or a global $ID on the page template to retrieve that variable.